# C++ saving the return value of the member function setf()

Tags: c++

To put it simply

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    ios_base::fmtflags initial ;

    cout << 10 << ' ' << 15.0 << '\n' ;
    initial = cout.setf(ios_base::fixed);
    cout << 10 << ' ' << 15.0 << '\n' ;
    cout.setf(initial);
    cout << 10 << ' ' << 15.0 << '\n' ;

    return 0;
}
```

This code should produce the following output:

```
10 15
10 15.000000
10 15
```

But it doesn't. What it does produce is:

```
10 15
10 15.000000
10 15.000000
```

So apparently the call to setf with *initial* as its argument isn't working right.

What's the Problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) will set flags, but not clear them. So `setf(ios_base::fixed)` will set the "fixed" flag, but `setf(initial)` will leave it set.

Use [`flags`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) to assign all the flags.

```
cout.flags(initial);
```

Comment: oh! can I infer from your words that setf only turns bits (on) and can't do anything else?

Comment: @Lockon2000: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

The bits from `std::fixed` are still present in the `std::ios_base::floatfield` portion of the mask. You need to clear that mask first *then* set `initial`:

```
std::cout.setf(initial, std::ios_base::floatfield);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, and your method worked too. But the first method is much simpler and clearer I will keep your way for more complex things :)